# Can I Customise The Order Table At Admin Side Of Partner.Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have a task to create an app or extension that changes the order table or customer table like adding a new column into it or highlighting some rows according to data or customers like good customer or bad customer something like this.
Is it possible or not? If anyone has an idea then please let me know
Thanks,
Saif ur Rehman

I try to create shopify app that can actually chnage in order table of admin side of pertner account